# Get and count number of true or false from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, boolean

From this MySQL statement, I would like to get and count those columns that is true to be displayed out in a page.

My following codes are:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM application WHERE shortlist = 1";
```

OR

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM application WHERE shortlist = true";
```

I am not sure why either of the statements is not being taken in. But it displays all that has been shortlisted or true.

Thanks!

Comment: How is `shortlist` defined?

Comment: If you have terminal access to the DB, what does `desc application;` display?

Comment: @GordonLinoff In the shortlist column, it is being displayed as either 1 or 0, with the datatype being tinyint.

Comment: @user1511724 . . . Then the first query should work.

Comment: @user1511724: Both of the queries are correct and should work. Can you also show your PHP code block used? And, what do you mean by *`it displays all that has been shortlisted or true.`*? Is it not just displaying a single row with count? Or is it fetching total count rather than shortlist count? Can you show some sample records?